# SO questions being scraped by third-party site illegitimately?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

I was searching Google a little bit ago for PHP logging practices and happened upon something that looked like SO content being lifted.

When [searching Google for my question](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20best%20way%20to%20share%20a%20logger) I noticed that two seemingly similar links were in fact nearly identical.  (They alleged copycat link is near the bottom of the results on page one whereas SO's link is the second result.)

The question that I found on the third party website, codeengine.org, is [here](http://codeengine.org/php-best-way-to-get-the-connection-and-logger-objects-for-all-classes/).  The same question is on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459729/php-best-way-to-get-the-connection-and-logger-objects-for-all-classes).  Looking at the page I noticed the sidebar had more questions like that.  Here is a question on SO [related to jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522653/jquery-remove-all-li-elements-with-empty-a-childs) and [its twin](http://codeengine.org/jquery-remove-all-li-elements-with-empty-a-childs/).

For what it is worth, the site does link back to SO for answering/commenting. However, there is no attribution to the original authors.  All of the questions I noticed say 'By Codeengine' at the top.

A [quick search on MSO about the website in question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcopycat-sites%5D+codeengine.org) didn't yield any results.

The question still begs whether or not this type of activity is acceptable to SO, and if not, what are the next steps?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I've passed this info onto SE and have gotten an email that it is being passed on to the correct folks within the company.  Sorry for the dupe.